Twilio cURL example for verifying an OTP?
I have spent days looking for cURL examples on the Twilio site, but all of their examples seem to be in Javascript and I don't know Javascript.
For instance, this page is mostly full of Javascript examples:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification-check#path-parameters
And, oddly, few of the fields mentioned there match the fields that I get back from Twilio when I make an OTP call, which makes me think I'm looking at the wrong verification, even though that does seem to be the main page of documentation for explaining how Twilio verification works.
I want to send an OTP and then verify it. The first part works correctly.
If I do something like this:
curl 'https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/VAb3527e002d39732b51c91a845f08d/Verifications' -X POST --data-urlencode 'To=+14348257694' --data-urlencode 'Channel=sms' -u AC33a3391a973d82a:3428e04e0bae2

Then an OTP is sent to our test phone. I get this in response:
{"status": "pending", "payee": null, "date_updated": "2024-12-11T13:56:58Z", "send_code_attempts": [{"attempt_sid": "VLcefcf94a49e3832d02eceef0", "channel": "sms", "time": "2024-12-11T13:56:58.014Z"}], "account_sid": "AC33a339755367abc587212531a973d82a", "to": "+14348257694", "amount": null, "valid": false, "lookup": {"carrier": null}, "url": "https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/VAb3527e2b51c91a865845f08d/Verifications/VE141164c73c3ca74495e51f4b", "sid": "VE141162a4c3ca74495e51f4b", "date_created": "2024-12-11T13:56:58Z", "service_sid": "VAb3527e002d39732b5845f08d", "channel": "sms"}%  

But then what? I have not been able to find a cURL example of how I would verify the OTP that was sent to our test phone.
I cannot find the correct URL. But also, the examples that I see on Twilio mention fields that do not exist in the response that I'm getting. Many of the examples mention "amount" and "payee" which makes no sense because we are not asking anyone to pay anything, we are only sending an OTP.
Can anyone point me to the correct documentation?
UPDATE:
I asked their Help AI Agent for help, and it offered me this cURL example:
curl -X POST "https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/VAb3527e0845f08d/VerificationCheck" 
--data-urlencode "To=+14348257694" 
--data-urlencode "Code= 326381" 
-u AC33a339755367ab2a:3428e04e0b5fae2
But when I call it I get:
{"status": "pending", "payee": null, "date_updated": "2024-12-11T14:09:14Z", "account_sid": "AC33a33975532531a9732a", "to": "+14348257694", "amount": null, "valid": false, "sid": "VEbaf2ae02b1822f946", "date_created": "2024-12-11T14:07:00Z", "service_sid": "VAb3527e05845f08d", "channel": "sms"}%   

I assume this is the part that matters:
"valid": false

I'm calling it with the code that just arrived on our test phone.
I've repeated this 4 times now. Every time Twilio responds with:
"valid": false

What else should I test?

From your dev tools network tab you can copy requests made by js as curl commands

I cannot find anything called a "dev tools network tab". When I search for that in the search bar, nothing comes up. How do I find the "dev tools network tab"?

You may check this doc thoroughly. https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/v2-api/formatting-validation

I don't understand. All I get is this: {"call_forwarding":null,"caller_name":null,"calling_country_code":"1","country_code":"US","identity_match":null,"line_status":null,"line_type_intelligence":null,"national_format":"(434) 825-7694","phone_number":"+14348257694","phone_number_quality_score":null,"pre_fill":null,"reassigned_number":null,"sim_swap":null,"sms_pumping_risk":null,"url":"https://lookups.twilio.com/v2/PhoneNumbers/+14348257694","valid":true,"validation_errors":[]}%

What should I be looking for here?

Here's how to do it with Firefox: https://scrapfly.io/blog/how-to-copy-as-curl-with-firefox/
And with Chrome: https://scrapfly.io/blog/how-to-copy-as-curl-with-chrome/

By default, a verify code is only valid for 10min. Is it possible that your code expired and you get the invalid response because of that? Because it seems to me you are using the right API.
PS: You can run the first request again to send another, new code.
